# JQuery Datepicker: how to explode the date in 3 fields?

Tags: jquery, datepicker

i'm using jQuery Datepicker into a form. Problem is that i need to pass values as 3 different fields (example: ?day=19&month=3&year=2013) and not as a unique date. Anybody know how i can do it?

Also, do you know hot to set calendar dimensions?

Comment: are you saying as default date

Comment: no, when you chose a date and then click on the submit button, i need to pass the date "exploded" in 3 parameters (day, month, year)

Comment: i think you can get by using getYear()....etc

Comment: could you show a practical example?

Answer (score 0):

you can use event of datepicker

```
onClose: function(dateText, inst) { 
        month = $("#ui-datepicker-div .ui-datepicker-month :selected").val();
        year = $("#ui-datepicker-div .ui-datepicker-year :selected").val();
    }
```

or you can explode the dateText by '-' which is default date format